# Garry's Mod - Props won't spawn after launching Lua script

Tags: lua

I have a test server for gmod. I've coded a script that works excellent when I launch it, but there is a lot of downsides with it.

I've tried to code a script that will simply change the users speed if they type a command like "!speed fast", or "!speed normal". It looks like this:

```
table = {}
table[0]="!help"
table[1]="!speed normal"
table[2]="!speed fast"
table[3]="!speed sanic"    
hook.Add("PlayerSay", "Chat", function(ply, message, teamchat)
    if message == "!speed normal" then
        GAMEMODE:SetPlayerSpeed(ply, 250, 500 )
    elseif message == "!speed fast" then
        GAMEMODE:SetPlayerSpeed(ply, 1000, 2000 )
    elseif message == "!speed sanic" then
        GAMEMODE:SetPlayerSpeed(ply, 10000, 20000)
    elseif message == "!help" then
        for key, value in pairs(table) do
            PrintMessage( HUD_PRINTTALK, value)
        end
    end
end)
```

As you can see the script change the users speed if they either type "!speed normal", "!speed fast" or "!speed sanic" in chat. The script also contains a table of every command, and it will be shown if the user type "!help" in chat.

When I launch the script it works excellent, but if I try to spawn a prop after I've launched it, the prop won't spawn. Even when I spawn a prop first, then launch the script and try to "undo" the prop, the "undo" function won't work! The script makes Sandbox gamemode completely useless, because you can't even spawn props!

I've tried to search a little bit around on the internet first, but I haven't stumbled across something like this yet, so I hope someone got the solution! Please help

Comment: you should use some text editor that is able to highlight keywords. so you won't overwrite Lua's essential libraries with your own stuff. From your code snippet I also don't see any reason why your table has to be global. Use local variables wherever possible.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that this is happening because you are overwriting the global `table`. [The table library contains helper functions for tables](https://www.lua.org/pil/19.html). Try renaming your table `table` to something else, like `commands`. I would also suggest you declare it as `local commands` so it does not replace any other global, so it does not interfere with anything else, like other scripts or library.

Also, as extra tips, lua tables are indexed with 1, So you could declare your renamed table as:

```
local commands = {
    "!help",
    "!speed normal",
    "!speed fast",
    "!speed sanic",
}
```

You could then iterate over it with a normal `for`:

```
for index = 1, #commands do
    PrintMessage(HUD_PRINTTALK, commands[index])
end
```

I think this makes it a bit cleaner, in my opinion.